# Boot failure: can't start TOR service and permission denied for locale-check in /etc/profile

Tags: boot, permissions, tor

These are the two problems I am facing while booting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

> Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (tor@default.service)

and

> Error found while loading /etc/profile:
>   /usr/bin/locale-check: Permission denied

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]